# Passing input back to form laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My form submission controller

```
// Code to get input from user and validation is done

// if validation fails
return Redirect::to(URL::route('showlogin'))->withInput();
```

showlogin method

```
$view->email = Input::flashOnly('email');
$view->password = Input::flashOnly('password');
return $view;
```

view page

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $email }}" name="email">
<input type="password" value="{{ $password }}" name="password">
```

The page does not fill the box with previous input when the validation fails. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel form helper to create form inputs to remember old input

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $email }}" name="email">
<input type="password" value="{{ $password }}" name="password">
```

will be

```
{{Form::email('email', Input::old('email') ) }}
{{Form::text('password', Input::old('password')) }}
```